# http://localhost:500/socket.io not found error

Tags: express, socket.io

Okay. I set up a socket.io system to get this error:

`GET http://localhost:500/socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=<somevalue> 404 NOT FOUND`

My client looks like this:

```html
<script>
const socket = io()
</script>
```

And  my server looks like this:

```js
const server = require("http").createServer();

const app = express();
app.use("/", express.static("dist"));
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
io.sockets.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("new socket connection");
});
```

`dist/index.html` contains the script from earlier.

I tried various solutions, but they are not working :/

Does someone know why?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your server is able to serve the request `GET /index.html` (or, equivalently, `GET /`), this gives your client-side code as response. But you have not shown us any server-side code that would serve the request `GET /socket.io`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `app` to create your http server:

```
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);

app.use("/", express.static("dist"));

const io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("new socket connection");
});
```

Comment: That didn't fix the issue for some reason...

Comment: I dont know then